# check if the index of an multiple dimensional array divisible by 2is

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have a multiple dimensional array and I only need the values of the index' from the outer arrat that are divisble by 2.

is there a way to do this within javascript?
something like:

```
if(indexOf(result.list) % 2 == 0){
}
```

I know indexOf wont work but something like that so that you can get the index of the array item

edit: I've searched a lot but I can't find anything that could have worked.

Comment: please share with us what you have tried yourself so far.

Comment: Not only does this sound like a homework assignment but you should provide an example of what you have tried so far and be specific with what you are struggling to understand.

Comment: Is there a way? Yes, there is. But first you need to show the problem you're trying to solve and explain where, and how, your attempts failed.

Comment: At least you can share an example with input data and the expected output to helps us understand what your goal is

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by filtering the outer array and mapping the filtered inner arrays.

```js
const evenIndex = (_, i) => !(i % 2);

var array = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 29, 21, 22, 23]],
    selected = array
        .filter(evenIndex)
        .map(a => a.filter(evenIndex))

console.log(selected);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```